# How to read data from xml in android

Tags: android, xml

I am using a service call where I receive xml data as response. 
I receive data as

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<note>
<status>4</status>
</note>
```

Now how can I get value '4' in status tag from that xml data.

Please help

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using XPath - tutorial can be found [here](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/java-xml-xpath-tutorial-parse-xml/)

Comment: I used this but getting exception as 
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: processing instructions must not start with xml (position:unknown 
 @2:2 in java.io.InputStreamReader@41228930) 

in line Document xmlDocument = builder.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes()));

Answer (score 1):

Everything is explained in the official doc:
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html